# ASP.NET Core 2.0 authentication based on host name

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I would say that classic ASP.NET Core 2.0 application with authentication consists of adding desired authentication service in `ConfigureServices` method in the *Startup.cs* file:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
});
```

This is fine as long as the authentication configuration is known during the time when `ConfigurationServices` method is called and is the same for all requests.

Our case needs different authentication configuration, let say based on host name:

```
company1.example.com // has own authentication configuration
company2.example.com // has own (probably different) authentication
```

For more details company1 has configured only Facebook and company2 has configured only Google authentication.

**Question**: Is it possible to have different authentication for each host or otherwise for each request? For instance once I know company I can load and use authentication configuration relevant for this request.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. Including using your `IConfiguration` or accessing http context as a service within your scheme events of facebook and google. Here is one of the cleanest ways of doing this. You can make your own scheme something like this:

```
public class MyCustomAuth : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{

    public const string SchemeName = "MyCustom";

    public MyCustomAuth(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory 
        logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        if (Request.Host.Value == "")
        {
            await Context.ChallengeAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        await Context.ChallengeAsync(FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (Request.Host.Value == "")
        {
            return await Context.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        return await Context.AuthenticateAsync(FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

You can add everything to your startup and set it up like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(MyCustomAuth.SchemeName)
        .AddCookie(...)
        .AddFacebook(...)
        .AddGoogle(...)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyCustomAuth>(MyCustomAuth.SchemeName, opts => { });
```