# ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 Remove Subdomain From Cookie Domain

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm working on a multi-tenant application that can have unlimited subdomains (i.e. tenant1.myapp.com, tenant2.myapp.com, etc.) and I'm having trouble with the Identity cookie.  It's authenticating for the entire domain and I would like to authenticate against the root-level domain (i.e. *.myapp.com or simply myapp.com).

I did find [the solution for the previous version of .NET Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227873/multiple-subdomains-cookie-in-asp-net-core-identity) (curse you progress), but that 2.0+, IdentityOptions.Cookies has been removed.

My question is, how would I implement something like this?

Comment: there might be an easier way if you could inject something into your startup.cs constructor. But in a long way, you can make a scheme something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111175/991609

Comment: Thanks Neville.  I'll give it a look and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, so the problem there is that I'm using Identity and I don't want to implement a custom auth handler.  I just want to authenticate someone for the TLD instead of the subdomain.

Comment: well, you will still be using identity. the auth handler i had created is technically extending the existing authentication and customizing your features. the defaults would still run

Comment: But they don't.  The login action authenticates, but redirects back to the login action so I'm assuming it's not creating the cookie or something.

Comment: for login are you using the services from identity? you should be able to control this using the cookie events too

Comment: I am.  Everything is out of the box Identity with exception of also implementing SaasKit NuGet package.  I don't know enough about the authentication to be able to wire up the cookie events.  Have a good starting place for me to look?